# Accepting only directories in with react-tsx<Input />

Tags: reactjs, typescript, input, material-ui, react-tsx

I need to accept local directories paths from the user, I am using react with typescript (with ).

I saw many posts recommending to add the `directory` and `webkitdirectory` attributes to the `input` tag, but this is giving me a typescript error (`Property 'directory' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttribues & InputProps'. TS 2322`).

Any kind of help would be much appreciated :)